# How to send curl request as a webhook url?

Tags: curl

I'm new to curl and webhooks, so please forgive the simple question.

how to make this curl request as a webhook url? (I've changed the bearer for security)

`curl -L -X POST 'https://tzkolxmyzqprcmykum.functions.supabase.co/hello' -H 'Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1N6MTk4ODA0MDE3OH0.alErGSQKe8VqttkAR5w4M5U8YspeaFBesiDdTyX43pI' --data '{"name":"Functions"}'`